# Use Gradle to manage dependencies and launch custom compilation script on legacy C++ project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to gradually migrate a really messy legacy C++ project to Gradle.

**tl; dr**

The project is compiled by an overly complicated system of shell scripts and each module contains an additional `.txt` file containing the dependencies. Those `.txt` files are parsed by the shell scripts and compiled in the order that you wrote them (yes, if you write the dependencies in the wrong order, the compilation will fail.

The results of the compilations are put in three common directories: `exe` for the executable files, `i686` for the `*.so` files (`exe64` and `x86_64` in the 64 bits case) and the `includes` directory for intermediate `.h` files & other files needed by the subsequent compilations. The same happens when compiling for Windows and not for Linux, but for now I'm focusing on the compilation for Linux.

This is how the repository looks like:

```
root
├── dependency
│   └── shared-dependency
└── project
    ├── exe
    ├── i686
    ├── includes
    │   ├── 32
    │   └── 64
    ├── lib1
    ├── lib2
    ├── lib3
    ├── lib4
    ├── (other directories)
    └── main
```

The `shared-dependency` is the first one that's compiled, the second is the `main` module (the executable) and then some `libs`. For the `libs`, as I said, the dependencies are defined in the `libs` folder.

The `shared-dependency` and `main` modules are always compiled, but not the libs: the lib that you choose to compile will define what will be compiled based on the dependencies that are defined in it's `txt` file.E.g.: the `txt` file in the `lib6` contains the string `lib2 lib1 lib5`, so the build procedure will compile, in this order: `shared-dependency`, `main`, `lib2`, `lib1`, `lib5`, `lib6`. Another example: the `txt` file in the `lib10` contains the string `lib2 lib5 lib28 lib8`, so the build procedure will compile, in this order: `shared-dependency`, `main`, `lib2`, `lib5`, `lib28`, 
 `lib8`. `lib10`.

As for now, if you create a new library, you have to manually define all it's dependencies and write them in the txt file (in the correct order!), so that you'll be able to build it.

**The question**

My goal, as a first step in this migration, is to use Gradle to:

1. Invoke the build scripts (and don't use Gradle's build, I would leave this to a later stage of the migration because I have to rip apart those messy scripts in order to do that).
2. Define the dependencies (bonus: define each dependency in the lib's subfolder and don't pollute the root `build.gradle`).

I have created a Gradle project in the `project` directory and programmatically defined all it's subfolders as includes in the `settings.gradle` file and defined the build task in the `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    task build {
        exec {
            commandLine "sh", "build.sh"
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't define dependencies! If I add something like that to the `build.gradle` file:

```
project(':lib1') {
    dependencies {
        archives project(':main')functionalities
    }
}
```

No matter what I choose instead of the `archives` word (like `implementation`), Gradle will complain that

```
Could not find method archives() for arguments [project ':main'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I'm totall new to Gradle, but if my understanding is correct, I have to apply a plugin in order to use dependencies, E.g. `apply plugin: 'base'`. But if I do this, I can't define anymore a build task because I get `Cannot add task 'build' as a task with that name already exists.`. And if I try with `task build <<< {` I get another error: `expecting '}', found 'build'`.

At the moment my understanding of the Gradle internal logic is almost zero, so I'm stuck.

Can be Gradle configured in a way that will suit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was frustrating, but in the end I was able to achieve what I wanted.

settings.gradle:

```
rootDir.eachDir { f ->
if(!f.getName().startsWith(".") &&
       !f.getName().startsWith("include") &&
       !f.getName().startsWith("lib") &&
       !f.getName().startsWith("lib64") &&
       !f.getName().startsWith("exe") &&
       !f.getName().startsWith("i686") &&
       !f.getName().startsWith("x86_64") ) {
        include f.getName()
    }
}
```

This will include all the subdirectories as modules

root build.gradle:

```
defaultTasks 'build'

allprojects {
    task build {
        doLast {
            exec {
                commandLine 'sh', "${project.name}.sh", '32', 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will invoke out custom build script for every submodule. Note that I had to add an empty project_name.sh to the root project, otherwise Gradle was complaining that the file was missing. I don't know if there's a setup to tell him to not try to call the build script in the root directory, I still have to research this.

Example of a submodule build.gradle:

```
build {
    dependsOn ":lib1:build"
    dependsOn ":lib2:build"
    dependsOn ":lib6:build"
}
```

This defines the submodules tat are dependencies of the current module.

And that's it!